# Removing outer border from the video image in video gallery

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, styles

Here is the link to the page.

```
http://www.braddockinfotech.com/demo/dvnonline/vod1/
```

On selecting a video from the video gallery on right side an orange colored dotted border is seen around it.How to remove this border.
I'm viewing this in `chrome`.In firefox it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

you have to reset outline styles for your list

```
#divplaylist ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  outline: none;
}
```

Comment: ok dat works fine, no more orange dotted border but when i try to move through the gallery using arrow key buttons i cant see the blue outline moving..

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `outline: none` on your `li`'s or your `a`'s.

Comment: but doing this removes the blue as well as the orange dotted border.I want only the dotted orange border to vanish

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
ul li a {box-shadow: none;}
```

Comment: but doing this removes the blue as well as the orange dotted border.I want only the dotted orange border to vanish